# Download a site directory - file server - GET with Offline Explorer

Tags: webserver, website, utorrent, repository, threadripper

I'm trying to download .torrent files from a directory that has authentication and sequential url in the files url:

```
site.com/torrents/download/{1-100}
```

I'm trying by Offline Explorer Pro software in Windows, but without success to download.

Comment: What operating system? Which download tool? What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Windows 10, Offline Explorer Pro, I tried to download it through the program options, if you have another one or a specific configuration, it would be very useful.

Comment: Why that tool? How have you used it? Does this site specifically state they support it? Does the site recommend a particular tool?